# How to hide ActionBar and NavigationBar after a certain delay time?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, delay, android-navigation

I would hide navigation bar and action bar of my app after some second that display don't get touched, and expand current view to fullscreen. 
Then if user touch the screen (or better if he swipe down), make visible both again. How to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `Handler` to **delay** certain actions.

```
 Handler h = new Handler();

 h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
         // DO DELAYED STUFF
         getActionBar().hide();
     }
 }, delaytime); // e.g. 3000 milliseconds
```

> The actions you take inside the `run()` method will be **executed after
>   the delay-time** you set.

Comment: Where do you put this in the code of `MainActifity.kt`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse, just create a new project and select "Fullscreen Activity": this is a good example on how to do what you want.

Comment: but i don't need to do it permanently. Just use that code then intercept ontouch event, or there's another way?

Comment: @giozh can you define better "permanently"? You want to hide Action Bar and Navigation Bar after x second. If user tap or swipe down, the bars appears again. Then after x second again they will disappear again and fullscreen will return back. If this is so, the Eclipse sample will show you how.

Comment: personally I would accept it as the correct answer (still valid in times of Android Studio) - the mechanics are a bit too long and complex for a stackoverflow answer, imho, and it's right there on the plate straight from the box.