# Loop for time delay when hiding actionBar

Tags: android, handler

This question extends this thread [How to hide ActionBar and NavigationBar after a certain delay time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674670/how-to-hide-actionbar-and-navigationbar-after-a-certain-delay-time)

This works for my application. But it only runs once. How can I make it to keep executing until a button is pressed (back button)

Btw this is a photoViewer app (part of) like Gmail app on android when you view a photo.

Update1: I actually have a touchListener to show() and hide() the actionBar again. So what I want is when I'm in imageView layout, the actionBar will disappear in 3000ms, then I tap to show(), then after 3000ms it should disappear again. Again, just like Gmail android app when you load a picture from email

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); // overlay mode
        setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_image);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();               
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_top);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);         


        // time delay to hide actionBar
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // DO DELAYED STUFF
                getActionBar().hide();
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
            }
        }, 3000); // e.g. 3000 milliseconds
....

    Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();                
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
        if(getActionBar.isShowing())
        {
            hideActionBar();
        }
        else
        {
            getActionBar.show();
            hideActionBar();
        }
    }
});

public void hideActionBar()
{
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // DO DELAYED STUFF
            getActionBar().hide();
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
            }
        }, 3000); // e.g. 3000 milliseconds
    }
}
```